# I need to access all posible combinations of column names with data_type=numberic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset containing multiple columns. I need to get all the posible combinations of the columns having numeric data and the use that combinations to calculate some metrics.
I was able to create a list with all the combinations but the problem is that when I try to pass those combinations to my code, I get the following error:

[image]

If I have to type the name of the columns manually, I do it this way :

```
cols = ["instructors_mean",'rating']
```

For example, if in my list the combination "instructors_mean",'rating' where in the position 10, how could I pass that to cols?

I tried `cols=[list_combinations[10]]` with no success.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `cols=list_combinations[10]` if `list_combinations` is a list of list.

Comment: I tried but I get the following error: KeyError: ('num_published_lectures', 'num_published_practice_tests')          I think it is because instead of () I need []

Comment: What's the result of `'num_published_lectures' in df.columns` and `'num_published_practice_tests' in df.columns`?

Comment: The result are a bunch of rows with numbers.

Comment: try cols=list(list_combinations[10]) - it looks like you might have a list of sets, rather than a list of lists. you can try to create combinations differently if this doesn't work

Comment: Aint´t working either...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to slice a dataframe with a tuple of columns :

```
cols = [list_combinations[20]]
# [("num_published_lectures"), ("num_published_practise_tests")]

df_train = df_train[cols] # this will trigger a KeyError
```

---

As a solution, you need to either use the [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accessor as per the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#) :

```
df_train = df_train.loc[:, cols]
```

Or generate a list of lists/combinations this way :

```
from itertools import combinations

numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include="number").columns
list_combinations = [[col1, col2] for col1, col2 in combinations(numeric_cols, 2)]

cols = [list_combinations[20]]
df_train = df_train[cols]
```